# Render image from request in bottle

Tags: python, post, python-imaging-library, webcam.js

My intention is to upload an image and do some image processing. For now, I intend to render the uploaded image.

I used the code [here](https://makitweb.com/how-to-capture-picture-from-webcam-with-webcam-js/) to build my front end and I wrote the backend in python using bottle, which is as follows:

```
@route('/test', method='POST')
def serve_image():
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    image = Image.open(request.body)
    image.show()
```

I get an errors as follows

> OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at
>   0x0000017386B53A40>

What am I missing?

**EDIT**:
When I print the whole request, this is what I get

> < http://localhost:8080/test>

Comment: How to access the raw image data in your bottle code depends on how exactly it's uploaded, whihc I can't tell from a quick scan of the link you provided. Try updating the code to dump / print the entire `request` object in that function, instead of opening it. You might find that's it's not in `requests.body` but somewhere else; or in a form-multipart format, etc.

Comment: @DanielleM.Edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is not very comprehensive, but the [full documentation](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/DOCS.md#submitting-images-to-a-server) is more useful:

> The image data is uploaded as part of a standard multipart form post, and included as a form element named `webcam`.

So rather than trying to pass the whole request body to Pillow, you need to pass just that element, using the `request.files` multidict, and accessing its `file` attribute to get the buffer:

```
image = Image.open(request.files['webcam'].file)
```